# Functional oracles

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np, oracles

In the traditional oracle Turing machine, the oracle is specified as a decision problem. Roughly speaking, one puts a string in the oracle tape, and asks whether it is true or false.

I am wondering whether it makes sense to consider a functional oracle. This means, one puts a string $x$ in the oracle tape, and guarantee the returned result $f(x)$ is polynomially bounded in length by $x$, and the oracle is supposed to return $f(x)$.

A very natural such an oracle is an FNP oracle, and one can define a class $P^{FNP}$.

Any study regarding this? Or the notion is not well defined? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: @Marzio having a function oracle might make a difference if the oracle access is somehow restricted, e.g. if only a bounded (sub-linear) number of queries are possible or if queries are non-adaptive.

Comment: @JanJohannsen: you're right ... I deleted the inaccurate quick comment.

Comment: Yes, they are quite common. You can even use search problems as oracles. Google for P^NP[wit] or for "witness-oracle".

Comment: Functional oracles are also widely used in higher-order complexity.  For instance, the class of second order basic feasible functionals ($\mathsf{BFF}_2$) may be defined in terms of oracle Turing machines, once a suitable notion of size of a function $\{0,1\}^\ast\to\{0,1\}^\ast$ is given.  See for instance this nice [survey paper](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~royer/archive/cbff1-a4.pdf) (the definition of oracle Turing machine is in Sect. 6).